Alert Condition Not Firing Correctly
Wrote an strategy and having an issue with same type of alert (buy or sell) firing multiple times in a row
i.e buy, sell, sell, buy, buy, buy, sell
I need only one alert (for buy or sell) to fire at a given time till the next condition cancel the prior
i.e buy, sell, buy, sell, buy
I’ll post just my logic to execute or not the alert, hopefully that will suffice to get a second opinion here:
if buy 
    buy_signal := true 
    sell_signal := false
    

if sell 
    sell_signal := true
    buy_signal := false


// buy condition represents the boolean check above + other logic in the strategy
buyCondition = buy_signal and close > signal 
sellCondition = sell_signal and close < signal 

buyAlert = buyCondition and not buyCondition[1]
sellAlert = sellCondition and not sellCondition[1]


// ALERT (SHOULD ONLY FIRE ONCE PER CONDITION MET)
if buyAlert and not buyAlert[1]
    alert(long, alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if sellAlert and not sellAlert[1]
    alert(short, alert.freq_once_per_bar)


issue shown on pictures bellow



Your logic is missing previous values ​​in the series
Try this:
buy_signal  = false
if buy and not buy_signal[1]
    buy_signal := true
else
    buy_signal := buy_signal[1]

sell_signal = false
if sell and not sell_signal[1]
    sell_signal := true
else
    sell_signal := sell_signal[1]


// buy condition represents the boolean check above + other logic in the strategy
buyCondition = buy_signal and close > signal 
sellCondition = sell_signal and close < signal 

buyAlert = buyCondition and not buyCondition[1]
sellAlert = sellCondition and not sellCondition[1]


// ALERT (SHOULD ONLY FIRE ONCE PER CONDITION MET)
if buyAlert and not buyAlert[1]
    alert(long, alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if sellAlert and not sellAlert[1]
    alert(short, alert.freq_once_per_bar)

